# Show and focus to menu

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, contextmenustrip

I have a `button` on a form, I want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, to show a `ContextMenuStrip`*(cmsJournal)*, unfortunately when I use that ***shortcut***, the button got focused, but no `KeyPress event` has been fired.

I want to use the following method when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

```
    private void PopJournalMenu() {
        cmsJournal.Show(btnJournal, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0 - cmsJournal.Height));
        tsmiAPPayment.Select();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first—I don't recommend creating shortcuts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>. In Windows applications, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is reserved for *keyboard accelerators*. They're the reason you see certain letters underlined in the captions of controls. For example, if you a Button control with the caption "&Journal", it will display as J̲ournal, and you will be able to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to "click" that button from the keyboard without touching the mouse, which is very important for accessibility reasons.

If you want to remain consistent with this behavior and your button is more like a drop-down button (i.e., one that shows a menu when it is clicked with the mouse), then your task is fairly simple. Label the button as demonstrated above (using a `&` character in the string to denote the desired accelerator, which in your case is `M`), and then wire up the code to display the drop-down menu just as you normally would in the `Click` event handler.

If you want to make your application confusing and hard to use, and you don't have a drop-down button, then you will need to manually intercept keyboard events and trick the window manager. It goes without saying that this will be more difficult.

The major problem you will need to overcome is focus. Only the focused control receives keyboard events, and only one control can be focused at a time. Therefore, if you have a Form that contains multiple controls in addition to your button (such as text boxes), any of those other controls could possibly have the focus instead of your button. That means they will receive the keyboard events and possibly react to them in their own way. This is why the `KeyPress` event isn't doing what you want (the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events would have the same problem). Those events are tied to a particular control and only fire when the control to which they are wired is focused.

If you want to escape this, you need to handle keyboard events at a "higher" level. The standard way of doing that in WinForms is at the Form level by overriding the [`ProcessCmdKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey.aspx). In your overridden method, you will test for your desired keyboard combination and, if appropriate, display the pop-up menu. For example:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.M))
   {
      cmsJournal.Show(btnJournal, new Point(0, 0 - cmsJournal.Height));
      return true; // indicate that you handled the key event
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Alternatively, you can call your `PopJournalMenu` method. I'm not sure what `tsmiAPPayment` is or why you need to call its `Select` method, though. In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877339/show-contextmenustrip-and-focus-it), I got the impression you were trying to use `Select` to ensure that the context menu was focused. You don't need to do that; the `Show` method already handles that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't know there is a drop down button, I'll look for it. In my previous method I used tsmiAPPayment.Select() to focus the first item in the context menu.

Comment: Thank you indeed, my mistake was in capturing the KeyPress event instead of the click event. My problem is solved, and my code is simple and clean, thank you very mych.